# run exe file to convert word to image in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i need convert word file (save binary in database) to image (JPEG) and download to client.
i create one windows application and generate image successfully. config this application to run on web application and work truly on my computer via VS2010.
After Upload to dedicate server not work.
When open word document exception and message is 
This command is not available because no document is open.
why this code not word?

Comment: We are going to need more details to help, at the very least the details of the exception.  Also check that all of you dependencies have been installed/added to the server (such as whatever library you're using to convert the word doc to an image).